# Removing the HTML elements from the tooltip

Tags: html, css

How can i remove the html tags because whenever i hover my house to a specific part, the data will be displayed but the html tags were also included. maybe theres something that needs to be changed.

**html snippet**

```
<div class="row " id="record_block" style='margin-left:4px;margin-top:20px'>
                    @foreach ($infomodel as $applicant)
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="card card-body" style="background: #ebefff;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 text-center">
                                    <a href="app-contact-detail.html">
                                    <img src="storage/image/<?php echo $applicant['photo_filename'];?>" alt="user" style="width: 85px; height: 80px;" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                                    <h5>
                                    <span style="z-index: 0;">
                                        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="" style="background: transparent; color: #0b719c; margin-left: 0px; z-index: 0;">
                                        {{ Str::limit($applicant->last_name . ', ' . $applicant->first_name . ' ' . $applicant->middle_name, 17) }}
                                        <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-af" title=""></i><br>
                                        <i>Doctor of Medicine</i><br>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class='tooltip-content' style="display: none;">
                                        <span style="margin-left: 15px;">
                                            <u><b>Fullname: {!! $applicant->last_name!!}, {!! $applicant->first_name!!} {!! $applicant->middle_name!!}</b></u><br/>
                                            Birthdate: {!! $applicant->birthdate !!}<br/>
                                            Country: {{ $applicant->country_name }}<br>
                                            Gender/CS: {!! $applicant->gender !!}/Single<br>
                                            Cellphone: <br>{!! $applicant?->country_code !!}{!! $applicant?->area_code !!}{!! $applicant?->tel_no !!}<br>
                                            Email:{{ $applicant?->email }}<br>
                                            Application ID:{!! $applicant?->app_id !!}<br>
                                            Date Last Updated: {!! $applicant->date_updated !!}
                                        </span> 
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    </h5> 
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-12">
                                        <address style="color: black; margin-left: 10px;">
                                            <abbr title="Email Address">Email:</abbr> <b>{{ $applicant?->email }}</b><br>
                                            <abbr title="Cellphone">Cellphone:</abbr> <b>{!! $applicant?->country_code !!}{!! $applicant?->area_code !!}{!! $applicant?->tel_no !!}</b><br>
                                            <abbr title="Application ID">Application ID:</abbr> <b>#{!! $applicant?->app_id !!}</b><br>
                                            <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-outline-primary" style="position: relative; z-index: 0;" title="Click to Manage" onclick="location.replace('manage_applicant-set_sessionvars.php?lnk=fi&purpose=2&a=2716');"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> Manage</button>  
                                                    </address>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
```

**screenshot**
[image: snippet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the attribute `data-html="true"` to this span :

```html
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="" style="background: transparent; color: #0b719c; margin-left: 0px; z-index: 0;">
```

As per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/tooltips/#options), it allows HTML in the tooltip.